# Show only specific transforms in timeline/graph editor

Tags: animation, graph-editor, timeline, dopesheet

I have a scene with hundreds of objects of which I want to animate the rotation, location and size. If I select all objects, the timeline gets a little messy. That's why I want to hide everything except the rotation keyframes. Then I want to hide everything except the location keyframes and so on. (I know I can lock the transforms of each axis manually but with hundreds of objects this is not feasible.) I am searching for a kind of shortcut that makes it possible to show only one transform at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is a slightly old thread now but just in case anyone else comes this way looking for the same answer I was. You can just type thee graph your want in the filter and it will only show that channel for all selected pbjects or bones. I believe what you are looking for is this:[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the *Graph Editor* you can select a track (for example *X Location*) and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to hide all the other ones, which will allow you to manipulate this track's keyframes only. To unhide, press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>.